# How to load postgis raster layers into R?

Tags: postgis, raster, r, rgdal

It is easy to get Vectorlayers into R from a PostgreSQL+PostGIS solution.

```
library(rgdal)
dsn="PG:dbname=plots host=localhost user=test password=test"
plots = readOGR(dsn,"Plots")
```

But how to do the same for raster layers stored in-db and/or out-db?
I am a bit confused if this is even possible as I haven't found any help or similar questions on the net.

At least readGDAL finds the driver, but returns error messages that I am unsure how to handle.

```
>dsn="PG:dbname=plots host=localhost user=test password=test port=5432"
>readGDAL(dsn,"map")

PG:dbname=test host=localhost user=test password=test port=5432 has GDAL driver PostGISRaster 
and has 0 rows and 0 columns
Error in offset[2]/(cellsize[1]/abs(gt[2])) : 
  non-numerical arguement in binary operator
additional: Warnings:
1: In dim(x) : no bands in dataset
2: In dim(x) : no bands in dataset
```

The imported raster should be fine as I can load it via QGIS.
If this is possible can someone provide a working example?

---

**OS**: Debian Jessie + PostgreSQL 9.4dev + PostGIS 2.. R.version > 3.0.0

**GDAL version**:

```
rgdal: version: 0.9-1, (SVN revision 518)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26
Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal/1.10
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012, [PJ_VERSION: 480]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
```

**GDALInfo** (even if pointed directly to table):

```
>dsn="PG:dbname=plots host=localhost user=test password=test port=5432 table=map"
>rgdal::GDALinfo(dsn)
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : Error retrieving raster metadata
```

Comment: what GDAL version? What does `gdalinfo` say about the datasource?

Comment: @MikeT Edited Question.

Comment: Outside R, what does `gdalinfo` from the command line show? What is the schema of `map`?

Comment: `gdalinfo  "PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname='plots' user='test' password='test' schema='public' table=map"` also refuses to return the raster metadata

Comment: Okay, I just tested a plain `raster2psql` and it works. It has something to do with my custom `map` table as explained here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118006/loading-raster-in-postgis-and-link-it-with-an-existing-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So assuming that the raster is correctly loaded in PostGIS you can get your raster via `readGDAL` in R in the following way:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

dsn="PG:dbname='plots' host=localhost user='test' password='test' port=5432 schema='gisdata' table='map' mode=2"

ras <- readGDAL(dsn) # Get your file as SpatialGridDataFrame
ras2 <- raster(ras,1) # Convert the first Band to Raster
plot(ras2)
```

Note the `mode`-tag at the end which is important depending on how you store your data!

Answer (score 3):

If this is still relevant, at the University of Florida, David Bucklin and I have released a [rpostgis](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rpostgis) package that provides bi-directional transfer between PostGIS and R for vector and raster data. The package does not rely on GDAL (and rgdal), and should be platform independent.

`rpostgis` relies on `RPostgreSQL` to establish a functional connection between R and the database. You can then use it to import PostGIS raster data type into R using the function `pgGetRast`, for instance:

```
library(rpostgis)
conn <- dbConnect(drv = "PostgreSQL", host = "localhost", dbname = "plots", user = "test", password = "test")
my_raster <- pgGetRast(conn, "map")
```

If the table is not in the `public` schema (which would be a good idea anyway), you will need to declare it using `c("schema", "table")` instead. The function assumes that the raster tiles are stored in the column `"rast"` by default, but you can change that with the argument `rast`. Now, depending on the size and other considerations, this may be significantly slower (but a lot more flexible) than using `readGDAL`. We are still working on it, but this is the cost of providing a "pure R" solution. You can also use the `boundary` argument if you are only interested in a subset of the entire raster (which will significantly increase the loading time).

Note also that there is `pgGetGeom` for points/lines/polygons, instead of using `readOGR`.